# Customisable chart from mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, charts, highcharts

I have a MySQL database and I am using PHP for server-side. I want to display some chart (Area/Gauge/Pie/Line etc) on webpage from MySql data.

I want to give option to user to select data (Filter data) for the chart. User can select chart type or select chart data.

Please advise me which chart library or application I can use.

This will be on my local webserver and will not be connected to internet.

I can't use google chart due to this.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Microsoft Excel :) *derp*

Comment: I am just looking for chart library. Not looking for any code.

Comment: Just try different libraries and choose what is the easiest for you. Or what looks the best in your opinion etc.

Comment: This isn't actually a programming question - you should post questions like this on softwarerecs in the future. Make sure you review their posting guidelines. Re: lib -  Pawfel is right, just try different libraries. http://www.highcharts.com, http://www.zingchart.com, http://www.amcharts.com, http://www.chartjs.org/ - there are literally dozens outside of Google Charts.